# How to design a Model in a Model-View-Presenter Pattern?

Tags: excel, vba, model, mvp

I want to store data in the following structure in a Model in order to use it in a MVP Pattern. I want to store a collection of collections of a custom class. The custom class has two properties. A string "name" and a Collection "members".

**This makes my property in my model a collection of a collection of collection. I doubt that this is a proper way of going about this.**

The reasons to structure the data like this are:

- I am using VBA-Excel
- The application I am programming is a material data base front-end and the user has to be able to select materials, materials state, temperatures of the tests, multiple curve types, other test parameters ect.
- User can select multiple curve types to be displayed. After that he will have the option of "narrowing down" the data. For example "I want data for 23°C with material state X"
- Each custom class should capture one of those narrow down options. Which means Filter and all selected Options for the Filter e.g. "Temperature" would be the Filter and the members of the colleciton then would be the selected temperatures like 0°C, 23°C, 42°C, 100°C.
- In the example above the temperature is not the only filter that can be applied to narrow down the data. There can also be the state of the material, the testing speed ect. All possible narrow down options should be summerized in a collection.
- This collection of the filteroptions are then specific for each curve type. For example you can vary the test speed on a tensile test, but you would not be able to filter for testing frequency. On the other hand on a fatique test you would be able to filter for testing frequency. That means that for every selected curve type there needs to be such a collection of narrow down options.

And that's the logic how I ended up with a collection of a collection of a collection.

**Is there a better way?**

Comment: All that filtering is going to be "fun" though. If you can model the data in XML format, you could leverage xpath queries to pull the nodes you need, and then "materialize" them into instances of some custom class. Ideally the data would be in a database, and you would have that backend doing the filtering work.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yeah I have a Oracle database as a back end. But I still need to "metacode" all SQL queries, which is definetly "fun". I will implemet it and see how it works, but still it is ridiculous IMO. The article was basically my guideline and the reason why I am doing MVP. Pretty concise article. Haven't read the follow up tough, need to read that.